# ggplot2 how to get 2 histograms with the y value = to count of one / sum of the count of both

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

I guess my question is simple (even if the title is not...) but I was not able to find any clear answer yet. I want to plot histograms of Reaction Times in a psychophysics task. I need to plot two of them on the same figure: one for correct responses, the other for incorrect responses.

I don't want to plot the absolute counts, but rather the relative proportion corresponding to:

For correct responses: `count(correct==1) / sum(count(correct==1) + count(correct==0))`

For incorrect responses: `count(correct==0) / sum(count(correct==1) + count(correct==0))`

For now I have that:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x=RT, color=correct)) 
    + geom_histogram(aes(y = ..count../sum(..count..))) 
    + stat_bin(breaks = seq(5,800,by=10))
```

But I'm not sure it is doing what I want (is the sum corresponding to the sum of both correct and incorrect responses?). I don't feel comfortable with the ..count.. etc, would anyone have a good recommendation for documentation about this aspect?

Thanks in advance.

**Edit:** The input data is:

```
df <- structure(list(RT = c(359L, 214L, 219L, 206L, 120L, 166L, 156L, 
       181L, 135L, 122L, 110L, 101L, 139L, 215L, 106L, 217L, 162L, 135L, 
       114L, 205L), correct = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
       1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L)), .Names = c("RT", 
       "correct"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -20L))
```

Here is a link to a plot I made earlier using base R which is exactly the output I want at the end. 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/nqn83pkoq7o0stv/RTexample.png
These are lines (but based on histograms, yellow for correct==1, blue for correct==0). The specific feature that I want is that both line together sum up to 1.

Comment: In a case like this I would summarize your data outside of `ggplot2` and then use that data frame as the source for plotting.  If you want further assistance though, we'll need to see some sample data or make up a small typical data set for testing.

Comment: I'll try to make a simple example. In the meantime, could you indicate me ressources to try to understand the ..count.. thing? It's not straightforward and very hard to search for.

Comment: Thanks, sorry I've not been clear. I'd like to try to avoid the precalculation. I'm just starting with ggplot2 and precalculating the lines/bar before plotting would actually send me back to what I was doing with base R or MATLAB. I was hoping I could perform it directly from ggplot2.

Comment: When I ask about "ressources", it is about the general syntax of ..count.. 
More specificcaly, I'd like to understand what the `y = ..count../sum(..count..)`is doing.

Comment: @Arun has given you a nice answer.  Regarding the `..count..` concept, check out the documentation for `stat_summary` here http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.2.1/  You can write your own function so you are positive it is doing what you want.  But, having done this many times, for a one-off or preliminary analysis, it will be quicker to pre-summarize.

Comment: Ok but then what is sum(..count..)? In other words, on what is the sum performed? If this is the bins, then how is `..count../sum(..count..)` different from ..density..?

Comment: @BryanHanson ok I will look at the link you sent me. Thanks for your help (Thanks Arun too of course). 

It is just as I told you that I want to understand the specificity and the power of ggplot2 so I don't want to do as I used to be (i.e. with base R or MATLAB), as far as possible, but as it should be done there.

Comment: @Arun ok I understand. I was just thinking that, since it was just a very minor change from the ggplot2() command I posted at the beginning that it could be performed inside it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

shora,

Brian Hanson is absolutely correct.  You really should stop trying to do your transformation as part of the 'ggplot' function.  I know it's tempting, but the in-plot transformation methods of 'ggplot' should be used more for data exploration rather than the creation of a predetermined graph.  You can quickly use the 'hist' function to get the data you need, transform the data, and then feed it into 'ggplot' for the actual graphing.  The best part about transforming your data manually is that you get to see all of it in action, and you won't have problems (as in your question) guessing whether or not the answers are correct.

You'll need to decide exactly how you want the two plots arranged, but that can all be done with 'ggplot'.  Here is an example of an outside transformation:

**Step 1**: Get the histogram values for [correct]=1.

```
correct_Hist <- hist(data[correct==1, 1], breaks=seq(5, 800, by=10), plot=FALSE)
```

**Step 2**: Get the histogram values for [correct]=0.

```
incorrect_Hist <- hist(data[correct==0, 1], breaks=seq(5, 800, by=10), plot=FALSE)
```

**Step 3**: Transform the counts.  Your explanation in the question is a bit ambiguous, and could be taken a couple different ways.  For this answer, I am assuming you do not want a histogram but rather that you want a bar chart that shows what percentage of a specific range of RT values is represented by incorrect or correct responses.  This is quite simple now that we have the counts.

```
correct_Bar_Values <- correct_Hist$counts / (correct_Hist$counts + incorrect_Hist$counts)
incorrect_Bar_Values <- incorrect_Hist$counts / (correct_Hist$counts + incorrect_Hist$counts)
```

**Step 4**: Plot it however you like.  Now that you have the raw values you want to plot, you can use any variety of methods to get it plotted.  I recommend the 'geom_bar' layer, rather than the 'geom_hist' layer, since you have already done the calculations.  You'll have to also specify the two different 'grid' viewports you want 'ggplot' to use, but if you need help with that, submit a second question.  This is how you can quickly make your data into a bar chart:

```
# The percentage of answers that were not correct
qplot(incorrect_Hist$mids,y=incorrect_Bar_Values, geom="bar", stat="identity", ylim=c(0,1))

# The percentage of answers that were correct
qplot(correct_Hist$mids,y=correct_Bar_Values, geom="bar", stat="identity", ylim=c(0,1))
```

Comment: Thanks @Dinre for the detailled explanation! I guess I misinterpreted ggplot2 by thinking it would take care of too much. I'll do what you suggested then.
Just to be accurate, what you suggested is exactly what I asked for except that the denominator of the divisions in Step3 are summed.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, `position="fill"` should meet your needs:

```
ggplot(df,aes(x=RT,fill=factor(correct,labels=c("Incorrect","Correct")))) +
 geom_bar(breaks=seq(5,800,by=10),position="fill") +
  scale_y_continuous("",labels=percent) + scale_fill_discrete("")
```

[image]

One histogram is based (the zero-level) at the bottom, the other at the top.